# Java, get Keys from Map that has data from FireStore

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting data from FireStore into a Map, my data in Firestore looks like this:

```
(Auto-Document ID)
    title="title1"
    body="body1"
(Auto-Document ID)
    title="title2"
    body="body2"
```

As I load them in a Map, it'll look like this:

> loadNoteCallBack: {rsmw3EkfIjUQxrzRiyy7={body=body2, title=title2}, sTEfYCcPK9lw77xWS8H5={body=body1, title=title1}}

"rsmw3EkfIjUQxrzRiyy7" and "sTEfYCcPK9lw77xWS8H5" are the Auto generated document ID-s

Now my problem is, I wanna extract the **titles** from them, and I don't exactly know how.
I've tried this:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();

for (String key : data.keySet()) {
    keys.add(key);
}
```

But I got back the document ID-s this way.

> titles: [rsmw3EkfIjUQxrzRiyy7, sTEfYCcPK9lw77xWS8H5]

How should I get the titles?

**update**

I think I did it. Is it a good solution for this problem?

```
    public static void loadNote() {
    db.collection("Datas")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            titles.add(document.getString("title"));
                            data.put(document.getId(),document.getData());
                        }                            
                        defaultEntitys.loadNoteCb(data,titles);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: `rsmw3EkfIjUQxrzRiyy7` & `sTEfYCcPK9lw77xWS8H5` going to be the key in your map ? & `title`, `body` will be the part of object which can be used as `value` is it what you are trying to do ?

Comment: yes, and I just wanna get all of the titles

Comment: You are correctly getting the auto-generated keys. What you want to get is a part of the value, not the key.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy I understand, how should I get the titles from the value then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

**Option 1:**

if use Firestore query reference directly, use QueryDocumentSnapshot class methods to get values from Firestore document

imports

```
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
```

code

```
  Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();
  ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> query = db.collection("data").get();
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = query.get();
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
  ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
    System.out.println("auto id: " + document.getId());
    String title = document.getString("title");
    titles.add(title);
  }
  System.out.println("titles = " + titles);
```

**Option 2:**

use `data.entrySet()` to get Key-Value pair, like below

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> o : data.entrySet()) {
    String key = o.getKey();
    Object value = o.getValue();
}
```

use any JSON lib like Jackson to parser value to JSON object or class object to get the title.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner approach using Java8 stream will be:

```
Map<String,FireStore> map=new HashMap<>();

FireStore f1=new FireStore("title1","body1");
FireStore f2=new FireStore("title2","body2");

map.put("rsmw3EkfIjUQxrzRiyy7",f1);
map.put("sTEfYCcPK9lw77xWS8H5",f2);

List<String> titles = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue())
        .map(FireStore::getTitle)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(titles);
```

Your FireStore object:

```
public class FireStore {
    private String body;
    private String title;
    public FireStore(String title,String body) {
        this.body = body;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getBody() { return body; }
    public void setBody(String body) { this.body = body; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
}
```

As information provided by you from the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection). You need to add following changes.

```
//asynchronously retrieve all documents
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = db.collection("cities").get();
// future.get() blocks on response
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = future.get().getDocuments();
List<String> titles=new ArrayList<>();
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
  titles.add(document.get("title")); //this will get titles and add into titles list.
}
```

Comment: What if I dont have a ForeStore object? In our project the user can put literally anything in the database, but there must be one named title

Comment: so your value will be a valid json ?or it will be a just comma separated string values which will always have `title` ?

Comment: a valid JSON. FireStore store the data I put there as a json, right?

Comment: can you post your json which you are getting from FireStore ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
"Get all documents in a collection"

Comment: I've edited my answer.(take a look at last part) I've used same code given by firebase & added a line of code to take titles. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where exactly can you import ApiFuture? I can't find in in the link

Comment: @MátéAntal Do you mean package for ApiFuture? I have provided imports for code, in my answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197562/836890

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase version 9 (web/JS)**
To **get a document keys** (fields) from a Firestore document collection:

```
 // import from firebase (including the db ref!)
    import { collection, query, getDocs, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
    // set up query - collection name can be passed as variable
    const q = query(collection(db, 'posts'), limit(1));
    const docKeys
 // You need to use async/await when calling on Firestore
    const getDocKeys = async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docKeys = Object.keys(doc.data());
        console.log(docKeys);
 // You can go further & push result to array and sort if needed...
      });
    };

// run function...
    getDocKeys();
```

Comment: the edit was made in order to correct the original code which was used in Vue 3/Quasar context - the docKeys variable was defined as a ref - const docKeys = ref(null) and consequently it's assignment used .value  - written as:  docKeys.value = Object.keys(doc.data())